# Как правильно выводить строку по буквам в java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int length = 1;
        String output = null;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите текст: ");
        String word = sc.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
            if (word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(i + 1)){
                length=+1;
            }
            if (word.charAt(i) != word.charAt(i + 1)){
                output = String.valueOf(+ word.charAt(i));
                if (length > 1){
                    output = String.valueOf(+length);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print(output);
    }
}
```

Подскажите, что исправить в этом коде.

Задание: Jaaaavvvva = Ja(4)v(4)a

ошибки:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at Main.main(Main.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: Есть у Вас строка `"Hello"`. Элементы этой строки нумеруются с нуля, следовательно последний будет иметь индекс 4. Длина строки 5. Вы проверяете, что значение итератора меньше длинны, а затем сравниваете два соседних. Ну так вот последний элемент проходит проверку по длине строки, однако при попытке обратиться к элементу с индексом на один больше вы получаете ошибку `String index out of range: 6`

Comment: @SanekZhitnik как по мне, автор знает про этот принцип, он просто не все предусмотрел

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Логи всегда говорят о выкинутом исключении, поэтому советую ознакомиться со примитивными исключениям.

Вот он источник ошибки `word.charAt(i+1)`.

Когда `i` достигнет последнего символа, мы запросим элемент `последний элемент + 1`, но ведь такого элемента нет, поэтому и вылетает исключение. Поэтому это нужно продумывать, хотя бы условием `i+1<length`

**По данному примеру:**

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Введите текст: ");
String word = sc.nextLine();
String output = "";
for(int i = 0, length = 1; i < word.length(); i++) {
    if (i + 1<word.length() && word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(i + 1) ){
        length++;
    } else {
        output+=word.charAt(i);
        if(length>1) output+=length;
        length = 1;
    }
}
System.out.println(word + " = " + output);
```

Вывод:

```
Jaaaavvvva = Ja(4)v(4)a
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код, просто ужас. Для вас писал с использованием Scanner.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //СЛУШАЕМ ВАС
        byte[] bytes = scan.nextLine().getBytes(); //
        int i = 0;
        int max = bytes.length;

        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream(max); // создаем буфер, первоначальный размер буфера = max

        // ДЛЯ СЧИТАВОДА БУКВ
        byte t = 0; // прошлый байт
        int c = 0; // количество байт одинаковых VVV = 3
        //

        byte a = 0; //для неделанья новой ссылки на обьект, хранит текущий байт
        while(i<max){
            //ОСНОВА
            a = bytes[i];
            i = i + 1;
            //

            if(t == a){ // прошлый байт равен текущему, ага +1
                c = c + 1;
                continue;
            }
            // то что не равно
            if(c>0){
                buffer.write(40); // (
                buffer.write(String.valueOf(c + 1).getBytes()); // вывести количество совпадений
                buffer.write(41);
                c = 0; // в количество одинаковых что-то осталось, стереть! 
            } 
            t = a; //записываем текущий в буфер для будующих сравнений

            buffer.write(a);

        }
        System.out.println(buffer.toString());//ЗАПИСЫВАЕМ В ПОТОК ВЫВОДА
        buffer.reset(); // если используем повторно функцию то чистим буфер
```

Comment: Чем лучше ваш код? Что такое a, b, c, t, i? Что такое buffer.write(40)?

Comment: Код практически рабочий, вставили и он работает. buffer.write(40); // ( . я даже пометил что 40 это символ ( по таблице ASCSII. Чем он лучше, тем что он в триста раз быстрее вашего кода, его легко перевести на любой другой язык программирования, легко понимаем интерпретатором а значит различного вида оптимизации или переводов некоторых конструкций в машинный код.

Answer (score 0):

так еще можно for fun xd

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append(scanner.nextLine());

        char[] arr = new char[stringBuilder.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < stringBuilder.length(); i++) {
            arr[i] = stringBuilder.charAt(i);
        }

        for (char ch : arr) {
            System.out.print(ch);
            Thread.sleep(200);
        }
    }
}
```